# Handling Spring MVC Exception as Validation Error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I currently have a Spring MVC servlet that process a file that is uploaded via the initial form page.

The request handler already does some validation on the file if it's missing certain requirements, but unfortunately it's unable to easily tell if all the requirements are met until the processing actually occurs.

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public String submit(@Valid FormData form, BindingResult result, Model model) throws IOException, ParseException
{
   if (result.hasErrors())
   {
      return "index";
   }

   processFile(form.getFile());

   return "success";
}
```

If an exception occurs at the processing step, I handle it in an `@ExceptionHandler` annotated method. However, this method requires having a second line for showing the error in the JSP page:

```
<form:input type="file" name="file" path="file" value=""/>
<form:errors path="file" element="label" class="error" for="file"/>
<c:if test="${not empty error}"><label class="error">${error}</label></c:if>
```

with the method itself looking like

```
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
public String databaseError(Model model, Exception e)
{
   model.addAttribute("formData", new FormData());
   model.addAttribute("error", "File failed to process. Please verify the contents of the file.");
   return "index";
}
```

Is there a way to leverage `BindingResult` to handle an exception as a validation error to avoid the redundant error message templating?

Comment: I have same problem, have you found any solution for it?

Answer (score 1):

You can catch the exception inside your request handling method, and then manipulate the BindingResult in your catch clause.

Comment: You know, I just completely dismissed that idea from my thoughts. Is there anything I should worry about when catching a `DataAccessException`? I remember reading somewhere that it's something you shouldn't be catching, which is why I just didn't think about it before.